# Assigning macros to a combobox

Tags: vba, combobox

I have been trying to assign 3 macros to a dropdown menu.

I created a combobox using Developer > Insert > ComboBox (not ActiveX controls) with three options: "Table 1", "Table 2" and "Table 3". Now, I want to assign a macro to each of those three options. If "Table 1" is clicked, then `macro1` would run; if "Table 2 " then `macro2`, etc.

I was able to create a menu through right clicking > Format Control and then choosing an input range.

But how do I link the dropdown options to macros?

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you mean by a 'module' in this context, do you mean a VBA module where you've written your own code? In which case would 'linking' the module mean running (some of) the code contained in it? It would also be helpful to know what software you're working with, answers might be slightly different dependent on which office software you're using (Excel, Access, Word etc).

Comment: Hi Aiken! Yes, I'm using Excel and programming in VBA. By module, I do mean VBA module and I have written code to extract some data. As with the explanation below, I should clarify, I am able to assign one macro to the combobox as explained by Jean-François. I am however, unable to assign multiple macros to the combobox. I.e. if I click on Table 1, it should run a macro from module 1. If I click on table 2, it should run a macro from module 5 and so on. Thank you in advance for your comments.

Comment: Jean-Francois' answer demonstrates clearly how to run different macros based on the selection in your combobox. If you need to run multiple macros for each selection, just expand the `Select Case` statement out to include them. [Here's a handy tutorial on Select Case](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/select-case.htm).

Comment: I think I understood what you mean. My problem was that I didn't know where to insert Jean-Francois' code. When I tried various permutations, I finally understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to *assign* a macro to the combobox.

1. Open a module and write a macro called e.g. `DropDown1_Change()`.
2. Right-click the combobox > Assign Macro... select your macro in the list > OK.

[image]
[image]

The assigned macro should determine which dropdown option was clicked, and call a different macro based on that choice. It could look something like this:

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    Dim c As ControlFormat
    Set c = Sheet1.Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat ' or whatever yours is called

    'Choose which macro to run based on the selected value in the combobox
    Select Case c.Value
    Case 1: Macro1
    Case 2: Macro2
    Case 3: Macro3
    End Select
End Sub

Sub Macro1()
    MsgBox "Macro 1"
End Sub
Sub Macro2()
    MsgBox "Macro 2"
End Sub
Sub Macro3()
    MsgBox "Macro 3"
End Sub
```